# Help with a preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to convert URLs, but not if they come after src=".  So far, I have this...

```
return preg_replace('@(?!^src=")(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.-]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $s);
```

It converts the URL, but even if it is before src="

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make that a look**behind** assertion.

```
(?<!^src=")
```